# Jquery panzoom + zurb foundation grid - what happened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

Pretty simple question I think. Basically what I have is a perfectly working prototype using timmywil's panzoom (https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom). The panzoom container is 100% of the screen. I want to drop in foundation for sites and add a top bar, and slide out side navs, but as soon as I add the foundation css, by panzoom container picks up a bunch of weird css and anything that should be hidden to the right on my panzoom container is still invisible/hidden when you pan to the right. I'm thinking foundation is somehow applying an overflow:hidden to my panzoom container or something.